# What is the sum of $\sum \frac{1}{n^2a_na_{n-1}}$ where $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$, how can we find the sum $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 a_na_{n-1}}?$$

It's possible to show that this sum converges using a direct comparison test, but I have no clue on how to evaluate this sum, everything I tried just leads to more complicated sums.

Comment: Note that an - a(n-1)= 1/n^2. So the term inside summation becomes 1/a(n-1) - 1/an
Telescopic now.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_na_{n-1}}=\frac{\tfrac{1}{n^2}}{a_{na_{n-1}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up and complete what was written in the comments:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{n^2a_na_{n-1}}=\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_na_{n-1}}=\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}$$
Which is a telescoping sum:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_n} = 1-\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = 1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: just as the hints suggested. What's new in your answer?